# the way to calculate the number of element in $\mathbb Z^*_n$ have order 2?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I want to show that if 
$n=pq$ such that $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes  the number of $\ (a,b)$ such that $a$ and $b \in \mathbb Z_n$ and $a\equiv a^{-1}\pmod n$ and $b(a+1)\equiv0\pmod n$ is $n+p+q+1$.
thanks
P.S:is the way  to calculate the number of element in $\mathbb Z^*_n$ have order 2?

Comment: I have fixed my solution (the initial version was incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, $a \equiv a^{-1} \pmod n$ is equivalent to $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$, and you have to take $a \in \mathbb Z^*_n$. We can use [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to solve this equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
  a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p \\
  a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod q
\end{cases}
$$
Both $\mathbb Z^*_p$ and $\mathbb Z^*_q$ [are cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_odd_primes) and have even size. That's why there are two solutions for each of the equations (you can check it e.g. by taking [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) of the equations). You can easily check that these ones fit:
$$
\begin{cases}
  a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p \\
  a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod q
\end{cases}
$$

Now let's look at $b(a+1) \equiv 0 \pmod n$. Again, we can use CRT to search for solutions modulo $p$ and modulo $q$ separately. So we have equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
  (a+1) b \equiv 0 \pmod p \\
  (a+1) b \equiv 0 \pmod q
\end{cases}
$$
If $a \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then the equation $2b \equiv 0 \pmod p$ obviously has a single solution $b \equiv 0 \pmod p$, since $p$ is odd. If $a \equiv -1 \pmod p$, then the equation is just $0 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, so any $b \in \mathbb Z_p$ fits. There are $p$ solutions with $a \equiv -1$ and one solution with $a \equiv 1$, in total $p + 1$ solutions.

Speaking of solutions modulo $q$, it is quite the same: there are $q + 1$ solutions. Any pair of a solution modulo $p$ and a solution modulo $q$ can be combined to obtain a single solution modulo $n$ due to CRT. So there are $(p+1)(q+1) = n + p + q + 1$ solutions.

**P.S.** 
The elements in $\mathbb Z^*_n$ of order $2$ are exactly the square roots of $1$ minus the single trivial unit solution (which has order $1$). You can use CRT again to find number of square roots. For module $n = p^k$ with odd $p$, there are $2$ square roots, because $\mathbb Z^*_n$ is cyclic and has even size. For $n = 2^k$, there is $1$ root for $k = 1$, $2$ roots for $k = 2$, and $4$ roots for $k \ge 3$, which follows from the [structure of multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_2).
For example. with $n = 2^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7$, there are $4 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 - 1 = 15$ elements or order $2$ in $\mathbb Z^*_n$. For $n = 2^2 * 3$, there are $4$ such elements.

Comment: :thanks your help